# What does pdf tell me that an induced probability measure doesn't? I.E what is the point of a pdf?

Tags: probability-theory

If we use the following definition:

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr{F},P)$ be a probability space, and let $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^k$ be a random vector. Let $P_X$ be the probability measure on $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^k)$induced by $X$. If $P_X$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t $k$-dimensional lebesgue measure $\mu$, with density $f_X:\mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}$, then $f_X$ is called the probability density function} of $X$, and $X$ is referred to as a continuous random variable}. For any set $B\in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^k)$, we have
$$
P_X(B) = \int_Bf_X \, d\mu = \int\dots\int1_B(x_1,\dots,x_k)f_X(x_1,\dots,x_k) \, dx_1 \dots \, dx_k
$$

Focusing on the first part, $P_X(B) = \int_Bf_X \, d\mu$, why do we WANT to know this? Does $f_X$, the pdf, tell us something that $P_X$ doesn't? I guess $P_X$ is defined on the borel sets, whereas $f_X$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^k$... Or is the answer just something along the lines that we want to work with Lebesgue measure instead of $P_X$, and $f_X$ allows us to do so?

Comment: If a random variable has a density then you can fully specify the distribution of the variable by specifying the density, or the CDF, or the pushforward measure. (The pushforward measure is what you're calling $P_X$.) Specifying the variable through its density is mostly for convenience. Part of why it is convenient is that in a lot of real examples, to specify the CDF or the pushforward measure you wind up having to write the density anyway (since you usually cannot compute the resulting integrals analytically).

Comment: So, in other words, it allows us to figure out what kind of random variable we are dealing with? If so, I like that answer. Thank you.

Comment: The "pushforward measure" is what is usually called the probability distribution of $X$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is somewhat unusual to specify the mapping $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R^n$. Often what one knows about $X$ is precisely the density or the cumulative distribution function.  How does one specify what the "induced probability measure" is except by specifying the density or the c.d.f.?

- Suppose $X,Y$ are independent random variables and $\Pr(X>t) = e^{-\alpha t}$ for $x>0$ and $\Pr(Y>t) = e^{-\beta t}$ for $t>0$, and you want to know the conditional expected value of $X$ given $X+Y$.  How do you do it?
- What if $R$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,1]$ and $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots$ are conditionally independent given $R$, and $\Pr(X_n=1\mid R)=R$ and $\Pr(X_n=0\mid R)=1-R$, for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$, and you want the conditional distribution of $R$ given $X_1+\cdots+X_n$.  How do you find it?
- What if $\Pr(X>x) = e^{-x/\theta}$ for $x>0$ and $N\mid X\sim\mathrm{Poisson}(X)$, and you want the marginal (or "unconditional") distribution of $N$.  How do you find it?
- Say you're doing a one-way analysis of variance with i.i.d. normally distributed errors with expected value $0$.  Your test statistic for testing equality of group means is the usual F-statistic, the ratio of within-group sums of squares to between-group sums of squares each divided by respective degrees of freedom.  How do we know what the distribution of the test statistic is, given that the null hypothesis is true?